# ModuleNotFoundError, while running a python script as root user in Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ping

I need to ping a website. Im using `pythonping` module. I have installed a module globally. When i write the following command in the terminal: `sudo python3 my_file.py` i got the following error:
`import pythonping ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythonping'`
What can it be? I was searching a lot and i didnt find any solutions, maybe i dont understand something :(

I tried to install this module with venv and then use shebag `#!`, but it didnt help again :(

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple Python versions. Try installing it with `python3 -m pip install pythonping`, this should install with the same interpreter that you'll run your script.

Comment: to continue adding with what @BoppreH said, also check your module is installed correctly by using `pip3 list | grep pythonping` and `pip list | grep pythonping`